# Passwordless SCP from automated script - NO ADMIN RIGHTS server side

Tags: password, raspbian, scp, authentication, key-authentication

I have a cloudways server with no admin rights. I have set up ssh keys using their website interface, to use ssh and scp without passwords from a raspberry pi 3b+ running stretch, however i am having some issues.

What works:
 - Manual log in with ssh from command line ssh tunnels using autossh (automatic scripts using systemctl)
 - Manual transfer of files using
 - scp from command line

What doesn't work:
- scp asks for password and denies access when using it within an automated script (systemctl)

I found similar questions online with solutions. However these solutions all involve changing permissions of directories (locally and on the server) and i can't try these sloutions because i have no admin rights on the server.

So my question is, why is scp working (passwordless) when i run it manually from the terminal, but not when run via systemctl? Is the issue definitely permissions in ssh directories? how can i debug this further from my local machine?

Comment: When you look in your service file (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/your-service.service`), which is started via `systemctl`, you may see a user given like `User=youruser`. Is it the same user you do manual passwordless scp with?
Passwordless logins are normal stored under `$HOME/.ssh/config`. This config is used, when you do it from shell I guess.

Comment: @syss Yes the User is the same. There is no config file in $HOME/.ssh/ (/home/pi/.ssh/config).

Comment: do you have something like a `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` file (or similar) in that directory?
if you are not sure what happens you can try to start a sshd server with the following command: `/sbin/sshd -D -d -p2222`. use the full path (maybe it's `/usr/sbin/sshd`) and a port >=1024, in this case 2222. (only root can open ports <1024)
then you can try the connection with your scp in verbose mode and try to find errors on both paths

Comment: @syss thank you for the suggestions. Yes I've got the rsa files, I've used them to set up the passwordless login. I'll try to debug using your suggestion.

Comment: You say manual SCP succeeds, but automated SCP fails? How are you automating the SCP copy? Cron? Try putting a whoami in the script to see if the user is correct and try scp -vvv